# Appending a pandas.DataFrame to one column of another pandas.DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

A similar question has already been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60994604/adding-a-pandas-dataframe-to-another-one-with-its-own-name), however the exact answer to what the OP wanted was not provided. So, I will try again. I have data with 4 columns, named `['date', 'log time', 'choice', 'dt between ROI']`. I would now like to filter this data based on two criteria, here named `['LED', 'drum']`. In other words, if particular rows of the original pandas.DataFrame correspond to `'LED'`, they get sorted under the `'LED'` column of the master dataframe, and if they correspond to `'drum'`, they get sorted under `'drum'` column of the master dataframe. In this way, both `'LED'` and `'drum'` columns would have the same 4 subcolumns as the original data, `['date', 'log time', 'choice', 'dt between ROI']`. Additionally, the `'LED'` and `'drum'` columns would not necessarily have the same number of rows.

To start, I first created the master dataframe with the above described structure:

```
master_df = pandas.DataFrame({
    'distraction': ['LED','LED','LED','LED','drum','drum','drum','drum']),
    '': ['date', 'log time', 'choice', 'dt between ROI', 'date', 'log time', 'choice', 'dt between ROI']
})

master_df = master_df.set_index(['distraction', '']).transpose()
```

This resulted in the desired final structure:

```
In: master_df
Out:
distraction     LED                                             drum
                date    log time    choice    dt between ROI    date    log time    choice    dt between ROI

In: master_df['LED']
Out:
date    log time    choice    dt between ROI
```

Next, my filtering function returns certain rows of the original dataframe:

```
output = filter_function(original_df)
```

Hence, `output` has the same structure as `original_df`:

```
In: output
Out:
date    log time    choice    dt between ROI
x1      x2          x3        x4
y1      y1          y3        y4
```

Then I tried appending this `output` to the created master dataframe like so:

```
master_df['LED'] = master_df['LED'].append(output, ignore_index=True)
```

which resulted in the following error:

```
ValueError: Cannot set a frame with no defined index and a value that cannot be converted to a Series
```

Next, I tried:

```
master_df = master_df['LED'].append(output, ignore_index=True)
```

which simply overwrote the above created structure. What I really want to achieve is this:

```
In: master_df['LED'].append(output, ignore_index=True)
Out:
LED                                             drum
date    log time    choice    dt between ROI    date    log time    choice    dt between ROI
x1      x2          x3        x4
y1      y1          y3        y4
```

and likewise:

```
In: master_df['drum'].append(output, ignore_index=True)
Out:
LED                                             drum
date    log time    choice    dt between ROI    date    log time    choice    dt between ROI
                                                x1      x2          x3        x4
                                                y1      y1          y3        y4
```

I am not sure, if pandas can handle empty rows, but I guess `NaN` would be OK. After the filtering is done, I then wish to recall the two filtered datasets by simply calling `master_df['LED']` or `master_df['drum']`. Is there a way to do this?

Many thanks for your help!

EDIT: Fixed `criterium` -> `distraction` to avoid confusion.

Comment: `master_df = master_df.set_index(['distraction', '']).transpose()`, there is no distraction column in master_df

Comment: Ah, yes, that's a typo, sorry. Fixed it. Thanks for bringing it up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The point of @Dani is that your code does not work. Anyway it works if one replaces `'criterium'` with `'distraction'` which I assume was the intent.

So to your question, you can do the following. You can prepend your `output` with another level of column multi-index so that it matches the column structure of `master_df`. Then you can safely `append` or `concat`

```
# if this goes into LED group; otherwise use 'drum' 
output_LED = pd.concat([output], keys = ['LED'], axis=1)
master_df2 = master_df.append(output_LED)
master_df2
```

produces

```
    LED drum
choice  date    dt between ROI  log time    choice  date    dt between ROI  log time
0   x3  x1  x4  x2  NaN NaN NaN NaN
1   y3  y1  y4  y1  NaN NaN NaN NaN
```

and

```
masket_df2['LED']
```

produces

```
choice  date    dt between ROI  log time
0   x3  x1  x4  x2
1   y3  y1  y4  y1
```

and

```
master_df2['drum']
```

produces

```
choice  date    dt between ROI  log time
0   NaN NaN NaN NaN
1   NaN NaN NaN NaN
```